# How to code a clear Select statement which returns a list of data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, express

Im working in a expressjs + sqlite small webapp for local use. But my problem is when I want to make a full select over a table. All my scripts are in JScript in `'use-strict'` mode.

I want to make one SELECT statement and collect data in a json array named `listadata`. But the problem is that: until I don't declare this variable outside of the `module.exports` group -i.e. as a global variable- I cannot return any list of rows. If I delete that declaration, my function doesnt return anything.

This module must return a full list of rows. Please can anyone explain why I must declare this variable as global?. Or maybe is there a way to deal with this kind of statement in a more elegant way according to Javascript?

```
var listadata = [];

 module.exports = {
listas2 : function(){
    var db = sqlite.connect();
    db.all("SELECT * FROM TBWOHPARG", function(err,rows){
        listadata = [];
        rows.forEach(function(row){
            listadata.push({
                _id: row._id,
                descripcion: row.descripcion,
                fechacreacion: row.fechacreacion,
                fechamodificacion: row.fechamodificacion,
                referencia: row.referencia
            });
        });
    });
    return listadata;
}
```

Comment: `'use-strict'` - so, not in strict mode then

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Sorry but in my case Im coding from a node server side. Ajax it outside of the scope of my problem.

Comment: Asynchronous is asynchronous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

db.all is asynchronous, so you will be returning `listadata` before it is populated

using callback, you can do something like

```
listas2 : function(callback){
    var db = sqlite.connect();
    db.all("SELECT * FROM TBWOHPARG", function(err,rows){
        listadata = [];
        rows.forEach(function(row){
            listadata.push({
                _id: row._id,
                descripcion: row.descripcion,
                fechacreacion: row.fechacreacion,
                fechamodificacion: row.fechamodificacion,
                referencia: row.referencia
            });
        });
    });
    callback(listadata);
}
```

but then when you call `listas2` you can't do

```
something = listas2();
// do things with something
```

it would need to be

```
listas2(function(something) {
    // do things with something
}
```

Which is the same pattern of code as the duplicate question, just you are using a different asynchronous function, i.e. `db.all` instead of `$.ajax`

There's also a `promise` solution in the duplicate, which I wont reproduce

Comment: Thanks!... this way of explanation is totally different from the previous. :)